# Switching target database from Snowflake to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm currently inserting data through batch-files into snowflake
the files look sth. like:

```
snowsql -c connection_name -d Database_name -s LANDING_ZONE -f C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\file.sql -f C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\file2.sql
```

the connection is established in a config file of snowflake.

```
[connections.example]
accountname = accountname
username = username
password = password1234
dbname = database_name
warehousename = warehouse_name
```

now I try to insert to PostgreSQL instead of Snowflake

I looked through the psql commands, and the config files for PostreSQL (pg_hba.conf, pg_ident.conf, postgresql.conf) and can't find a way to create/declare a the connection (buttom code)
Is there a way to build a similar connection (top code connection_name) to PostgreSQL?

Feel free to ask if something is unclear or missing.
Sorry for the inconvenience, it's my first question here.

Comment: [The connection service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if the following PostgreSQL kb article can help here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html

After defining the connection string in a file, we can use the following command to establish a connection:

```
$ psql service=mydb
```